# Domain delegation

Tags: networking, dns

I registered a domain, say `abc.pl` at a registrar, say `registrar.pl`. Recently I've installed and configured a BIND server on my home computer to host the `abc.pl` domain. Now as I understand it I have to delegate my domain on my hitherto `registrar.com`. The registrar has a GUI panel with the option "external DNS servers" where one can type new DNS servers.

I have some questions about the details:

1. Am I right that the registrar updates the NS records at the upper domain
   registrar (that is [NASK](http://www.nask.pl) in the case of `pl` domains) to point now to my home DNS server/servers?
2. What do they do with the SOA record describing the `abc.pl` domain? Am I right that it just updates the record in something like this?

   The old version (before the delegation):

   ```
   ...  
   $ORIGIN abc.pl.  
   @       IN      SOA     ns1.registrar.pl. root.registrar.pl. (  
   ...  
   @               IN      NS      ns1.registrar.pl.  
   @               IN      NS      ns2.registrar.pl.  
   ns1             IN      A       registrar_dns_1_ip  
   ns2             IN      A       registrar_dns_2_ip
   ```

   The new (after the delegation):

   ```
   ...  
   $ORIGIN abc.pl.  
   @       IN      SOA     ns1.mylocal.pl. root.mylocal.pl. (  
   ...  
   @               IN      NS      ns1.mylocal.pl.  
   @               IN      NS      ns2.mylocal.pl.  
   ns1             IN      A       mylocal_dns_1_ip  
   ns2             IN      A       mylocal_dns_2_ip
   ```
3. If I'm right that it should set `AA` a `Authoritative Answer Flag` to `0` to indicate that from now it isn't an authoritative server for the `abc.pl` domain?

Comment: You do not necessarily need to make the DNS point to an external server if you can just manage the DNS from the hoster's server. All you need to do then is make an A record point to your IP address.

Comment: Yes, i know that but as i wrote i'd like to run & host the domain on my home computer. Could You then try to answer my 2 questions?